# Need explanation on php syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Form this code...

```
session_start();

$page = "index.php";

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('shopping cart') or die (mysql_error());

function products(){
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, product_name, price FROM products ORDER BY id DESC');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0 ){
        echo "There are no products to display";
    }
    else {
        //grabs associated array from products
        //mysql_fetch_assoc , turn results into an array
        while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
            echo '<p>'. $get_row['product_name'] . '<br/>'. $get_row['price'].
                '<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</p>';
    }
}
```

Please tell me what does these do?

1. session_start();
2. $page = "index.php";
3. mysql_num_rows($get)
4. mysql_fetch_assoc($get)

Comment: for the functions see: http://php.net

Comment: [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php); [$page = "index.php";](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php); [mysql_num_rows($get)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php); [mysql_fetch_assoc($get)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: You should really read up on the PHP-basics (or programming basics, even) before attempting to tackle that code.

Comment: How can you not understand what a simple variable assignment like `$page = "index.php";` does? Or are you really asking what that variable is used for? It's not used at all in the code you posted, it's probably used somewhere else in the script.

Comment: already read that site but you know there are programmers there who is not good in english like me. I read the explanation but it's deep

Comment: i want an explanation with no technical words

Comment: ofc i understand $page = "index.php" but what is it used for?

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow isn't suited for basic language tutoring. Find a book in your native language, then start from there.

Comment: @isabel - `$page = "index.php"` is used to assign a string value (`index.php`) to a variable (called `$page`)..... if you need help with understanding that, you really do need to start with a few tutorials on programming.... there are thousands of them on the interwebz, in most languages

Comment: yeah i know youre telling me to read books or read some on w3c. I tried but i dont understand the technical terms.

Comment: As you haven't indicated a language, all I can suggest is English tutorials (http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/variables.html`.... StackOverflow isn't a site for providing in-depth non-technical explanations of general programming principles, that's way too long ad detailed for the simple question/answer format

Answer (score 1):

[`session_start()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> Start new or resume existing session
>
> Creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

[`mysql_num_rows()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

> Get number of rows in result
>
> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use `mysql_affected_rows()`.

[`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

> Fetch a result row as an associative array
>
> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is equivalent to calling `mysql_fetch_array()` with MYSQL_ASSOC for the optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array.

An associative array has a "key" and a "value", while a non-associative array just has a "value" at a certain position. Here's an associative array:

```
$test = array(
    'name' => "John Doe",
    'age' => 42
);
```

You can access the individual elements of the array like this:

```
echo "Name: ", $test['name'], " Age: ", $test['age'];
```

A non-associative array wouldn't have the `name` and `age` keys; just "index numbers":

```
$test = array("John Doe", 42);

echo "Name: ", $test[0], " Age: ", $test[1];
```

"Moving the data pointer ahead" basically just means that the same row of data won't be fetched twice. The MySQL driver will mark the row as already-processed, so the next call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will return the next row.

When there is no more data to fetch, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will return `false`, and the `while(...) {...}` loop will exit.

**`$page = "index.php";`**:

This is simply setting a variable to the string `"index.php"`; it's not anything special. You'd have to see where `$page` is used in the code.

Comment: what does associative array means

Comment: Added an explanation for associative arrays and the internal data pointer.

Comment: how does the condition while works? it only stored mysql_fetch_assoc($get) to $get_row. Is it like the loop will keep going while there is still row that is not fetched yet?

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :) If this solved all of your problems, please accept the answer by clicking the checkbox in the middle of the voting arrows.